# is it possible make a group by query with different filter depending on the field?

Tags: ms-access

I wonder whether is it possible to make a group by query with several filter depending on the field :

Here is one example of what I want to do :

I have one table tPay :

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
| idPay       | PayDate      | Pay           | IsBonus  |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 1           | 2018-01-12   | 1000,01       | 0        |
| 2           | 2018-01-26   | 1500,01       | 0        |
| 3           | 2018-01-28   |  100,20       | 1        |
| 4           | 2018-02-04   |  200,55       | 1        |
| 5           | 2018-02-04   | 1200,20       | 0        |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
```

I need to query by month the total pay, the main paid and the bonus:

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| PayMonth    | TotalPay     | Bonus         | Pay             |
|             | no filter    | isBonus = 1   | isBonus = 0     |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 2018-01     | 2600,22      | 100.22        |  1500,02        |
| 2018-02     | 1400,75      | 200.55        |  1200,55        |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Is possible to do this in single query or do I have to make several group by queries?

I manage to set a query to have the first two columns, but I do not know how to go on :

```
 select DateSerial(Year([PayDate]),Month([PayDate]),1) AS PayMonth, Sum(tPay.Pay) AS TotalPay,
 from tPay
 GROUP BY DateSerial(Year([PayDate]),Month([PayDate]),1);
```

If you have any idea I will appreciate so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more streamlined query is --

```
SELECT Format(PayDate, "yyyy-mm")    AS PayMonth,
       Sum(Pay)                      AS TotalPay,
       Sum(Iif(isBonus = 1, Pay, 0)) AS Bonus,
       Sum(Iif(isBonus = 0, Pay, 0)) AS [Pay-notBonus]
FROM   tPay
GROUP  BY Format(PayDate, "yyyy-mm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this `IIf()` expression:

```
IIf(tPay.isBonus=1, tPay.Pay, 0)
```

When `isBonus=1`, the expression returns the bonus (Pay) amount; otherwise it returns zero.

So for each row of the raw data, that expression returns the values you want to add.  And to do that at the `GROUP BY` level, put it inside `Sum()` like this ...

```
Sum(IIf(tPay.isBonus=1, tPay.Pay, 0)) AS bonus_pay
```

That should give you what you need for the third column.  For the last column, use similar logic but change the `IIf` condition to `isBonus=0`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I was looking for. I knew that there was a way to include condition but I did know how...

Comment: @HansUp, surely you can agree with all your experience in MS Access, that it is high time the database dialect upgrades to modern ANSI standards. Vote with me in [recommending](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) to the Access team to upgrade its SQL dialect such as the portable `CASE` statement, consistent `LIKE` wildcard, less restrictive `JOIN` and `ON` clauses, plus more.